# Electron-Mocha Testing Threejs on Travis CI

Tags: three.js, mocha.js, electron, travis-ci

I am running threejs in electron and my test are running on electron-mocha. When I run the renderer tests they pass locally, but fail on [travis ci](https://travis-ci.org/jeremythuff/Gluon/builds/225474065).

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExtension' of null

I have tried many different things surrounding xvfb and xvfb-maybe, but nothing seems to get change behavior.

My test command is:

```
ELECTRON_PATH='./node_modules/.bin/electron' electron-mocha --renderer -R spec \"./dist/**/*.spec.js\"
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The error looks like that WebGL is disabled.

Comment: Disabled in electron's chromium, or at the OS level?